# Why need I input value for AUTOINCREMENT field in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I create a SQLite table, the field id is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
I remember the AUTOINCREMENT field will be passed a value by system when I insert a record in SQL Server database, so I try to use `insert into mytable values ("AA")` to add a record,
but I get an error, so I have to use `insert into mytable values (2,"BB")` to add new record, why?

```
-- Describe MYTABLE
CREATE TABLE "mytable" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "mycontent" TEXT
)
```

Comment: what error did you get for first query? will it work if you change it to `insert into mytable(mycontent) values('aa')`?

Comment: Thanks! you are right. I make an error synax insert into mytable values ("AA"), it should be insert into mytable(mycontent) values ("AA")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto increment field is also just like other fields. Since you are going to insert only one field among two created in the table, you have to explicitly specify them. for ex.
insert into mytable(my content) values('hi');